# One Page Layout Each Page Full Browser Window Size

Tags: css, html

Ok. First let me say I can see how this question could be answered a hundred different ways and is somewhat coder opinion and thus this question could be construed as against Stack Overflow policy. So let me clear this up by saying I am looking for a standardized answer.

This is my first attempt at a single page layout and I want to make sure I am coding it correctly to perform across all browser types.

From what I have seen so far the best way to get each section (aka page) of a single page layout to be 100% of the screen on all browsers is this.

```
html{height:100% !important;width:100% !important; margin:0px; padding:0px;}

body{height:500% !important;width:100% !important; margin:0px; padding:0px;}

.page {height:20% !important; width:100% !important;}
```

Meaning the body height is set to 100% * (Total Number of Pages) and each section defined with the class .page would be 100% / (Total Number of Pages)

While I see how this make sence. It feels like bad practice to set the height over 100%. **So my question is this: Is this the proper way to do this according to best practices?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of best practices regarding this.

Your solution looks like it would work.

However if you're targeting just modern browsers, a probably more natural solution to do this is using `vh` and `vw` units. Giving the `.page` a `height` of `100vh` will give you the current height of the viewport. Hence you can make them flow naturally and you don't need to change the `body` height in case you want to add an additional page and you don't have to set the height of `html` as well.

Comment: Well that's about a billion times more elegant! I have played around with vh, vw, vmin, and vmax trying to get a responsive font size but never had much luck with it. It's always been too big or too small depending on screen size.

Comment: Ok I am actually running into an issue with this method. I have two bootstrap columns side by side on the first page that when viewed on a mobile browser resize to stacked columns making it larger than the mobile screen. However instead of pushing down the second page until after all the content. It overlays the column on page 2's background. How can I address this?

Comment: Anyone looking for the answer to above it's simply make the .page property min-height: 100vh; instead of just the height prop.